# How to go fullscreen in Flash?

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I would like to create a button that makes my flash fullscreen.
But this line:

```
stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
```

... does not work. Why?
(I'm opening my swf directly in Chrome.)

*Edit:*
There seem to be consensus that I should embed in HTML.
Can somebody provide a snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for SWFObject as it works fine for every browsers. Check this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Go Fullscreen</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">                 
            var fo = new Object();
            function initFlash()
            {
                fo.flashvars = {};
                fo.params = {
                    allowScriptAccess: "always",
                    allowFullScreen: "true"
                };
                fo.attributes = {};         
                swfobject.embedSWF("swf/FlashFile.swf", "flashcontent", "100%", "100%", "10", "swf/expressInstall.swf", fo.flashvars, fo.params, fo.attributes);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="flashcontent"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            initFlash();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can download the swfobject javascript file and expressinstall swiff here:
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/downloads/detail?name=swfobject_2_2.zip&can=2&q=

Good luck,
Rob

Answer (score 1):

In the generated html there should be a variable/parameter "allowFullScreen". You need to set this to true.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
 codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,18,0"
 width="600"  height="400" id="fullscreen" align="middle">
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
<param name="movie" value="fullscreen.swf" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#333333" />
<embed src="fullscreen.swf" allowFullScreen="true" bgcolor="#333333" width="600" height="400"
 name="fullscreen" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```